# Prove the continuity in the composition function.

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, function-and-relation-composition

If $g$ is continuous at $c$

and $f$ is continuous at $g(c)$

Then prove that $(f\circ g)$ is continuous at c.

To prove this I have done something:
Given:
$$\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=g(c)    \tag 1    
$$
and,
$$ \lim_{g(x)\to g(c)}f(g(x))=f(g(c)) \tag 2
$$
Now,$$ \lim_{x\to c}(f\circ g)(x)=\lim_{x\to c}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to c}(g(x)))=f(g(c))=(f\circ g)(c) \tag 3
$$

**Is the second equality in (3) true ?**

If no then please prove it.

And if yes then what is then, what is the requirement of (2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the second equality is true **since** we're given $\;f\;$ is continuous at $\;g(c)\;$ and this means that

$$\lim_{x\to g(c)}f(x)=f\left(\lim_{x\to g(c)}x\right)=f(g(c))$$

*no matter how* $\;x\to g(c)\;$ , and since $\;g(x)\xrightarrow [x\to c]{}g(c)\;$ because we're **also** given that $\;g\;$ is continuous at $\;c\;$ , we're done.

Comment: It is given f is continuous at g(c) not at c

Comment: Of course, @Singh. Already corrected.